# Would you be able to recognize this linear algebra method?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, gaussian-elimination

[image]
[image]
**Example:**
[image]
I found this method in a lecture note. Would you be able to recognize this linear algebra method? What is the English name of this method?

Also I need to find a video about this method to understand how it works.

Comment: It looks suspiciously like Gaussian elimination followed by backward substitution.

Comment: @ekkilop Yeah it seems like but I need to find the exact method with using this exact table.

Comment: @ekkilop Method called as Modernized Gauss Algorithm Method (direct translation from Turkish)